# Can't filter datagridview between two datetimepicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Good day, I am trying to filter the datagridview between two datetimepicker.

I have tried

```
public void LoadAllBorrowHistory()
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (cboStatus.Text == "All Records")
        {
            gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT bb.borrowID,  bb.bookTitle,  bb.studentNum, (s.lastName + ' ' + s.firstName) AS Name, bb.status FROM tblBorrowedBook as bb INNER JOIN tblStudent AS s ON bb.studentID = s.studentID WHERE dateBorrowed BETWEEN '" + dt1.Value + "'AND'" + dt2.Value + "'", cn);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i += 1;
                gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["borrowID"].ToString(), dr["bookTitle"].ToString(), dr["studentNum"].ToString(), dr["Name"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT bb.borrowID,  bb.bookTitle,  bb.studentNum, (s.lastName + ' ' + s.firstName) AS Name, bb.status FROM tblBorrowedBook as bb INNER JOIN tblStudent AS s ON bb.studentID = s.studentID WHERE status LIKE '" + cboStatus.Text + "%'", cn);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i += 1;
                gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["borrowID"].ToString(), dr["bookTitle"].ToString(), dr["studentNum"].ToString(), dr["Name"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

**It is throwing an error**

> 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

I have set the datetime values to `DateTime.Now` so I don't why I am getting this error. Please help.

Comment: You will have to convert the c# datetime values to a correct sql datetime value, then it should work

Comment: @kemchan: Not an expert in SQL workings, but does dt1.Value.ToString() solve the problem?  Also a ↑ for the GoodDay greetings ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by using parameterized queries instead.

```
public void LoadAllBorrowHistory()
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (cboStatus.Text == "All Records")
        {
            gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT bb.borrowID,  bb.bookTitle,  bb.studentNum, (s.lastName + ' ' + s.firstName) AS Name, bb.dateBorrowed, bb.dueDate, bb.status FROM tblBorrowedBook as bb INNER JOIN tblStudent AS s ON bb.studentID = s.studentID WHERE dateBorrowed BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", dt1.Value);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", dt2.Value);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i += 1;
                gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["borrowID"].ToString(), dr["bookTitle"].ToString(), dr["studentNum"].ToString(), dr["Name"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dateBorrowed"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),  dr["status"].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT bb.borrowID,  bb.bookTitle,  bb.studentNum, (s.lastName + ' ' + s.firstName) AS Name, bb.dateBorrowed, bb.dueDate ,bb.status FROM tblBorrowedBook as bb INNER JOIN tblStudent AS s ON bb.studentID = s.studentID WHERE status LIKE @status AND dateBorrowed BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", cboStatus.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt1", dt1.Value);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt2", dt2.Value);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i += 1;
                gunaDataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["borrowID"].ToString(), dr["bookTitle"].ToString(), dr["studentNum"].ToString(), dr["Name"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dateBorrowed"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dueDate"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), dr["status"].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```